# Tool to print out functions being called during run time？

Tags: c, debugging, trace

I am looking for such kind of a tool on either Unix/Linux platform which can achieve:

1. I have the source files and I compiled the application myself (the source code is in C, although I don't really think it matters here)
2. I want to run this application while every function calls are printed/logged to a stdout/file

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int square(int x) { return x*x; }
int main(void) {
    square(2);
}
```

And when I run this program it will print out

- main
- square

I understand that `gdb` can do this to some extent, or `valgrind` but they all do not do exactly what I want. I am just wondering if such a tool exist? Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/corelight/cwrap ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `gcov`:

```
$ gcc -O0 --coverage square.c
$ ./a.out
$ gcov -i square.c
$ awk -F '[,:]' '$1 == "function" && $3 > 0 {print $3, $4}' square.c.gcov
1 square
1 main
```

(where the number is the number of times the function was called (we skip the ones that are never called with `$3 > 0` in the `awk` part)).

That's typically used for code coverage (how much of the code is being tested). You could also use the `gprof` code profiling tool (typically used to figure out how much time is spent in various areas of the code):

```
$ gcc -O0 -pg square.c
$ ./a.out
$ gprof -b -P
            Call graph


granularity: each sample hit covers 2 byte(s) no time propagated

index % time    self  children    called     name
        0.00    0.00       1/1           main [7]
[1]      0.0    0.00    0.00       1         square [1]
-----------------------------------------------

Index by function name

   [1] square
```

Answer (score 9):

To have the executable print the function names as they are being called, on a GNU system, you can use `gcc`'s `-finstrument-functions` option and `dladdr()` to translate addresses to function names.

Create a `instrument.c` like:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define TRACE_FD 3

void __cyg_profile_func_enter (void *, void *)
   __attribute__((no_instrument_function));

void __cyg_profile_func_enter (void *func,  void *caller)
{
  static FILE* trace = NULL;
  Dl_info info;

  if (trace == NULL) {
    trace = fdopen(TRACE_FD, "w");
    if (trace == NULL) abort();
    setbuf(trace, NULL);
  }
  if (dladdr(func, &info))
    fprintf (trace, "%p [%s] %s\n",
             func,
             info.dli_fname ? info.dli_fname : "?",
             info.dli_sname ? info.dli_sname : "?");
}
```

And then compile your executable as:

```
$ gcc -O0 -rdynamic -finstrument-functions square.c instrument.c -ldl
$ ./a.out 3>&1
0x400a8f [./a.out] main
0x400a4f [./a.out] square
```

(here using fd 3 to dump the function names to keep it separate from the stdout and stderr streams).

You can adapt the code to only print the `dli_sname` if you only want the function name.

Comment: This resembles DTrace a little bit I think. I will definitely give it a try.